# Mule message incompatibility issue between 3.3 to 3.4

Tags: java, mule

I'm facing an issue with two different versions of Mule. We have an external system which runs on Mule 3.3 and we are on 3.4. When a message from external system is received we see following exception. However if a message is sent from Mule 3.4 and received by same version there is no issue.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.mule.session.DefaultMuleSession.getPropertyNamesAsSet(DefaultMuleSession.java:215)
    at org.mule.session.DefaultMuleSession.<init>(DefaultMuleSession.java:81)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.copy(DefaultMuleEvent.java:951)
```

Comment: Do you really want the session to be carried from one Mule to the other? If not, just turn it off.

Comment: Thanks David. we don't need session. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these cross-Mule interactions happen over HTTP, you can turn sessions off for HTTP like that:

```
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides
        sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
</http:connector>
```

Comment: It worked. We use JMS connectors, added service-overrides at the connector level as you suggested and worked :) This is a great help. Thanks David